# Twitter bootstrap 3 - text inputs in MVC razor view are hiding first couple charaters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, razor, view

I am using twitter bootstrap 3 with horizontal forms and form groups in my ASP.Net MVC razor app:

```
<form action="SomeAction" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3 control-label">
        @* label *@
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        @* textbox *@
        @* validation *@
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have the following in my layout template because every view will be a form and I don't want to have to style every control or view separately:

```
$('input[type=text]').addClass('form-control');
```

With text inputs, this is what I get:

[image]

The first 1-2 characters are hidden until I click in the control, which then shows them:

[image]

I am using IE 10. It doesn't happen in google chrome:

[image]

Not sure how to resolve this so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what was causing it. I have the following javascript in my _Layout.cshtml view:

```
$('input[type=text]').addClass('form-control');
```

Once I removed it and applied the class in the control it rendered properly:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Manufacturer, new { style = "width: 400px;", @maxlength="50", @class = "form-control" })
```

Text inputs seem to be the only one with this problem. textarea and select don't have the same behavior.

I wanted to avoid having to put the bootstrap class in every single control in every single view. If anyone knows of a better way please let me know.

**Update**

It turns out the padding style (12px) in the bootstrap.css (version 3.0.0, line 1712) is causing the problem:

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px; /* this line is causing the problem */
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
          transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
```

Hate to alter the bootstrap css. I am overriding it temporarily in my _Layout.cshtml view:

```
$('input[type=text]').addClass('form-control');
$('input[type=text]').css('padding', '6px 0');
```

Comment: I find it very unfortunate that you have to explicitly specify the class for every form control in BS3; as opposed to BS2 which implicitly styled all `input` elements. I raised this as an issue on the Bootstrap Githup page here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10957